# Pandas show both unique counts and unique values?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ('a', 'aa'),
    ('b', 'aa'),
    ('c', 'bb'),
    ('d', 'bb'),
    ('e', 'cc'),
    ('f', 'cc'),
    ('h', 'cc')
], columns=['group', 'id'])
```

I do a groupby to show the count of unique values and also the unique values themself. Here is what I am doing now:

```
df1 = df.groupby(["id"])["group"].nunique()
print(df1)
id
aa    2
bb    2
cc    3
df2 =  df.groupby(['id'])['group'].agg(['unique'])
print(df2)
id           
aa     [a, b]
bb     [c, d]
cc  [e, f, h]
```

However, I am trying to have these two shown next to each other (one column shows the count and one shows the values as shown below. Is there any way to get that?

```
id    count values
aa    2     [a, b]
bb    2     [c, d]
cc    3     [e, f, h]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = df.groupby('id')['group'].agg(count='nunique', values='unique')
```

**Output**

```
>>> res

    count     values
id                  
aa      2     [a, b]
bb      2     [c, d]
cc      3  [e, f, h]
```